# Broken Dashboards and panels in a report of Logi Analytics (Info)

Tags: report

I had a report that functioned well but crashed recently. The error messages were not helpful.

The main page displayed a dashboard with multiple panels that held data tables, but the dashboard was broken suddenly.

I discovered that when I deleted the dashboard and all panels, and I replaced them with an empty dashboard and an empty panel, the report was still broken and shown me the same error message which is showing below.

Has anyone dealt with the error before? Are there any solutions? Any that are simple and small?

Source code and Error messages

[source code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKTMI.png)

```
Logi Debugger Trace Report
There was an error while processing your request.

The error was:

**There was a problem evaluating an expression. The error was: "Error: in expression ".**
Compute Data Operation Plan 

    View Data Operation PlanData Operation Group 1:
    - Retrieve data
    
    Data Operation Group 2:
    - ReportCenterFilter ID="rdReportCenterFilter"
    
    Data Operation Group 3:
    - CompareFilter ID="cmpIsVisual"
    - CompareFilter ID="cmpNotCurrentUser"
    
    Data Operation Group 4:
    - DeDuplicateFilter
    
    Data Operation Group 5:
    - AggregateColumn ID="RowCount"
    
    Data Operation Group 6:
    - DataLayerLink ID="dlSharedFrom"

 

Data Operation Group 1 of 6 

View Group Details (1 Items)Details for Data Operation Group 1 of 6

Load data into engine
- Running as a separate Data Operation Group since the next step requires access to the full data file.
```

- Generating this debugger information increases the overall elapsed time.

[logi debugger img 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK7bI.png)
[logi debugger img 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBfq3.png)

```
Detailed Error Report

There was an error while processing your request.

Message:
There was a problem evaluating an expression.  The error was: "Error:  in expression ".

Source:
rdServer

Stack Trace:
   at rdServer.rdScriptEvaluator.Eval(String sExpression, String sErrorResult, Int32 iValueCountPassed)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.k(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ax(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ak(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ax(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ak(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.q(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ak(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.s(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ak(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.r(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ak(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.q(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ak(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.s(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ak(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.r(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ak(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.q(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ak(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.s(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ak(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.r(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ak(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ax(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ak(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.q(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ak(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.s(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ak(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.r(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ah(XmlElement& A_0, String A_1)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ak(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ax(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.rdDashboard.a(XmlElement& A_0, XmlElement A_1)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ak(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.az(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.ak(XmlElement A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.a6(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.bf(XmlElement& A_0)
   at rdServer.PageBuilder.BuildHtml(String RequestedPage)
   at rdServer.ResponseBuilder.BuildResponse()

 

Inner error:

Message:
Error:  in expression

Source:
Microsoft.VisualBasic

Stack Trace:
Error:  in expression 
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container.InvokeMethod(Method TargetProcedure, Object[] Arguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, BindingFlags Flags)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ObjectLateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
   at rdServer.rdScriptEvaluator.Eval(String sExpression, String sErrorResult, Int32 iValueCountPassed)
```

[rdServer error image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiMdM.png)
[rdServer error image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvxG8.png)

Answer (score 2):

I have no errors when copying your code into a new report, so I suspect there might be an issue with your project directory (a support file, perhaps?). I would suggest starting a new project, and slowly copying over your reports one at a time, to confirm; alternatively, restore the directory from a backup, if possible, to see if that resolves the error.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report ID="Dashboard">
   <StyleSheet StyleSheet="newStyleSheet.css" />
   <ReportHeader />
   <Body>
      <Dashboard2 ID="testDash" SaveFile="@Function.AppPhysicalPath~\SavedDashboards\a.Dashboard_Default_.xml">
         <Panel Caption="panel header" ID="pnlTest1">
            <PanelContent>
               <Label Caption="test Label" />
            </PanelContent>
         </Panel>
      </Dashboard2>
   </Body>
   <DefaultRequestParams Interval="0" />
   <ReportFooter />
   <ideTestParams />
</Report>
```